# Combining two rows with a , in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to achieve something as below in HIVE.

Input:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
 A1    B1     C1    D1   E1
 A1    B1     C2    D1   E1
 A3    B3     C3    D3   E3
 A4    B4     C4    D4   E4
```

Output:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
 A1    B1    C1,C2  D1   E1
 A3    B3     C3    D3   E3
 A4    B4     C4    D4   E4
```

Row 1 and Row 2 are similar except for Col3 in input. In output it should be separated by `,` instead of two rows.

Comment: can this be the case for other columns too? for eg: col1 is different on 2 rows and all the other columns are the same?

Comment: no.. It is just for Col3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collect_set` does exactly what you want. Below query should do:

```
select col1, col2, col4, col5, concat_ws(",", collect_set(col3))  from <table> group by col1, col2, col4, col5;
```

`collect_set` removes duplicates gives you a unique list. If you have duplicates in col3 and want to preserve those, you can use collect_list instead. So if your col3 has C1, C1, C2; using collect_set gives "C1, C2". Using collect_list gives "C1, C1, C2"

Edit: The concat_ws converts output in the required format.

Comment: It does the magic, but it concatenates the value with `["` and `"]`. Anyways that could be handled... Thanks for the answer

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can use concat_ws to parse it in the required format.